# How do I add an active class to Foundation accordion dd element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation, accordion

I'm trying to figure out how to add an active class to `<dd>` in Foundation's accordion. Right now active state is only enabled for the content in the div, not on `<dd>` which is what I'm after.

Issue also described here: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/1061-accordion-foundation-5

Current:

```
<dd>
<a href="#panel1">Title</a>
<div id="panel1" class="content active">Content</div>
</dd>
```

Desired:

```
<dd class="active">
<a href="#panel1">Title</a>
<div id="panel1" class="content active">Content</div>
</dd>
```

Here's the code for current foundation.accordion.js:

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
'use strict';

Foundation.libs.accordion = {
name : 'accordion',

version : '5.0.1',

settings : {
  active_class: 'active',
  toggleable: true
},

init : function (scope, method, options) {
  this.bindings(method, options);
},

events : function () {
  $(this.scope).off('.accordion').on('click.fndtn.accordion', '[data-accordion] > dd > a', function (e) {
    var accordion = $(this).parent(),
        target = $('#' + this.href.split('#')[1]),
        siblings = $('> dd > .content', target.closest('[data-accordion]')),
        settings = accordion.parent().data('accordion-init'),
        active = $('> dd > .content.' + settings.active_class, accordion.parent());

    e.preventDefault();

    if (active[0] == target[0] && settings.toggleable) {
      return target.toggleClass(settings.active_class);
    }

    siblings.removeClass(settings.active_class);
    target.addClass(settings.active_class);
  });
},
```

Comment: What about making a [Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery for this

```
on_some_event {
    $("dd").addClass("active"); //adds 'active' class to all <dd> elements
    $("dd").removeClass("active"); //removes 'active' class from all <dd> elements
    $("dd").toggleClass("active"); //toggles 'active' class for all <dd> elements
}
```